# Flash button inside Movie Clip is not responding to clicks

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am very new to Flash. I've built a Movie Clip, inside this Movie Clip there is a button. There button does not respond to clicks (when I hover over it my cursor remains the same). I know it's not a problem with the button, since when I put the button directly in the main scene it works just great. Any ideas?

Note, I am using flash CS4 with ActionScript 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your movieclip's mouseChildren property is set to true.

Comment: @Tegeril, thank you! I don't know why, this is a default setting?